# add php code with innerHTML

Tags: php, javascript, innerhtml

let's say I have a php page with a javascript script (script src...) can I use innerHTML to put additional php code in it? lets say

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML = "<?php $test=90312; echo $test; ?>";
```

will this get executed?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that? Decare first $test in PHP, then assign its value to js var, then append innerHTML to the js variable. Since a declared but not used PHP var has nothing to do with what the user sees, you don't need to additinally add PHP that does not do anything (I mean the part "$test=90312;")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the PHP will not be executed. PHP is executed server-side, while JavaScript is not executed until after the webpage has been loaded by the browser (client side), so it has no way to run the PHP (unless you're using a very odd browser).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be executed php first and render the result in its place together with the javascript before sending it to the browser client in which case the javascript is then executed.